# Using besides in a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> **Besides** gaining my career, the course will surely contribute to our country’s wealth.

Is this use of *besides* correct?

Comment: Yes, though *gaining* is not.

Comment: Gaining your career means as if you are trying to gain something from some source. Careers could be furthered not gained. See Edwin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Besides furthering my career, the course will surely contribute to our
>   country’s wealth.

'Correct' – but this is rather like

> As well as being the architect of the Third Reich, Hitler liked small
>   dogs.

The two propositions are not closely related enough to be put into a single sentence.

Comment: Perhaps this is a little hard on the OP. The person is probably applying for funding for a course, at the expense of his/her country's taxpayers. The cost may need to be justified on the basis that it will be of benefit to the country.

Comment: Yes, I think you got it right. That is what I really wanted to mean.

Answer (score -3):

No, it is completely unintelligible.

Comment: Hi, English is not mother language. It is my second language. What I really try to say is master course will contribute to/gain my career development and also will contribute to the economy of my country. I thought using besides will shorten the sentence and nail the meaning. Could you please rewrite my unintelligible sentence for me? thanks.

Comment: see Edwin Ashworth's comment below..."furthering my career" or advancing my career would be a lot better fits for what you want to say rather than "gaining"

Comment: @user69898 - You might want to check out [ell.se] (and perhaps [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722) as well.